# How to find a formula for a perfectly balanced attack/defense system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let's say I have three characters and I want that they "fight" each other. Each character have an attack skill called A and a defense skill called D. Both skills are represented by a simple integer value.

If A of the attacking character is greater than D of the defending character the attacking charachter wins. Simple as that.

I'm trying to find a way to create an equation out of this to calculate valide values for each A and D for each character. Eventually every charachter wins at least 1 time and looses 1 time, to get a 50% success quote for each character.

The overall goal is to find a solution where I can define ***n* characters** with values for A and D where every charachter has a winning quote of (around) 50%.

This is my approach so far: A matrix showing the results of the "game":

[image: game results]

0 means "even" or no valid game, 1 means a win, -1 means a loss. A character may not attack it's own kin, so A cannot fight A. And I also consider attacks, to keep it simple.

For starters I created a table for those three characters that seem to to work:

[image: attack/defense stats (3 players)]

This is pretty easy. Now I tried to raise the amount of characters by two (to keep a 50% winning-rate I need to increase the number of players by two).

[image: attack/defense stats (5 players)]

I'm just choosing random numbers with no system right now. This is still kind of easy, but adding two more, I stuck. It's getting to confusing just moving around numbers. And I do not find any logic or system that could match to this problem.

So I am wondering: What would be an approach to create a solvable (un-)equation system? To me it almost looks like a sinus and cosinus function (ref. the first matrix above).

Is this even possible? Is this something that I have to do manually? I bet there's an theory covering this kind of problem.

Comment: Why does your table for three characters work? Doesn't $A$ win $3$ out of $4$ scenarios (attacking against $C$ and defending against either $B$ or $C$)?

Comment: If you compute A+D for each character, it is certainly a good indicator of Total-Force. In your 1st try, A+D is the same for all characters, and, no surprise, the game was raising to equilibre.

Comment: Hint: Take your first example and duplicate character $A$ and character $C$. What happens? Also, you don't really need to deal with non-integers, instead of $4,5$; $3,5$ and $0,5$, you could also use $5$, $3$ and $0$ for the $D$ values.

Comment: @joriki Guess I need to add more details: I only want to count active attacks, defending does not count - for now - to keep it simple

Comment: @PeterKošinár That's kind of enlightening. Gimme some time to process this to find a good balancing and stats that are not too boring.

Comment: @Lourrran Almost, the third "Force-Stat" has 4,5 instead of 5,5. Nevertheless, it feels like this is a good hint, too. I'm just not able to see how to use it. :/

Comment: Sorry, we both made mistakes. In 1st example, sum A+D is not the same for all characters, but situation is not fair. Character A never looses when opponent attack him, and he is able to win when he attacks C. C is always loosing when someone attack him and he we wins only when he attacks B

Comment: @Lourrran Right... that exactly describes the struggle I have!

Comment: If the win condition depends on which character is the attacker, do you want two fights between each pair of characters, one with each as the attacker?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a formula that simply returns a complete set of att/def-stats, but after some "research" I ended up with a quite complex python script that allows me to simulate the card games with randomized parameters.
My conclusion is: There's no perfect formula, because a perfectly balanced set of character attributes would make the game not playable. The characters need to be "out of balance" to give one character a chance to win.

If I want to implement perfectly balanced characters, I need to add a strategic momentum, where player's decision influences the game more than the "chance".

You can see the Python script here:

https://gist.github.com/nickyreinert/05dc269fc5091d9ecc7b03836970cab0